# Need help in constructing a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in writing a case statement. I've a column in one of my table which has some values and I would like to generate a string out of that values. Below is the column which I've in my table along with the output which I would like to see.

`Risk Score`

```
1.70
2.10
2.60
3.00
3.20
3.60
3.80
4.00
4.10
4.30
4.60
4.90
5.20
5.40
5.50
5.60
5.80
6.10
6.40
6.60
6.80
7.10
7.50
```

So my requirement is I want a case statement where if the risk score is >0 and <=3 it has to got to `Low` bucket, if the risk score is >3 and <=6 it has to got to `Medium` bucket, if the risk score is >6 it has to got to `High` bucket

Regards,

Vikas

Comment: Let's see what you have tried after reading about Oracle CASE Expressions. Since these don't have fall-throughs, I suspect you will have to have some sort of normalization technique, where you create logic that initializes a param to Low, Med, High and use that in your case. But YMMV. Show some code, though.

Comment: Google Oracle Case.  Then try to write a query.  If not working, then post your query.  Then maybe someone will help you.  Here's a good reference how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of short-circuit evaluation of clauses in a CASE expression:

```
...
    case when risk_score > 6 then 'high'
         when risk_score > 3 then 'medium'
         when risk_score > 0 then 'low'
         else                     'some_description_here'
    end
        as bucket
```

The `ELSE` part is for risk score *other than* `> 0`. (Risk score of 0, or negative if possible, or - more likely - `NULL`, if that is possible in your table.) If you don't need an `ELSE` branch, it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `CASE`

```
SELECT val
    ,CASE 
        WHEN val > 0
            AND val <= 3
            THEN 'LOW'
        WHEN val <= 6
            THEN 'medium'
        WHEN val > 6
            THEN 'High'
        END AS bucket
FROM table1;
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+--------+
| VAL | BUCKET |
+-----+--------+
| 1.7 | LOW    |
| 2.1 | LOW    |
| 2.6 | LOW    |
| 3   | LOW    |
| 3.2 | medium |
| 3.6 | medium |
| 3.8 | medium |
| 4   | medium |
| 4.1 | medium |
| 4.3 | medium |
| 4.6 | medium |
| 4.9 | medium |
| 5.2 | medium |
| 5.4 | medium |
| 5.5 | medium |
| 5.6 | medium |
| 5.8 | medium |
| 6.1 | High   |
| 6.4 | High   |
| 6.6 | High   |
| 6.8 | High   |
| 7.1 | High   |
| 7.5 | High   |
+-----+--------+
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e7eb/3)**